# How to write code on unprotect sheet in review tab

Tags: excel, vba

I'm unprotecting my sheet by entering password.When I click on OK apart from Worksheet protection changing I want to write soem other code.How do I do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the built-in Excel unprotect dialog is called from other code, such as in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564841).  Any additional actions you want to perform can easily be added to this code.