# How to detect a cell is selected for editing in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of readonly cells.After that all other cells are editable.I want to know how can I detect this cell editing event.Like if cell A25 is edited,I want to call a procedure.
If Cell(A25).edited then do this.Some thing like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event as highlighted in [my answer to one of your other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564841).

May I suggest that now would be a good time to go and learn a bit more about Excel events and what you can and can't do with them, rather than asking multiple similar questions?

The following links may help:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/events.htm

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExcelWorkbookEvents.htm

Answer (score 1):

Though i'm not sure if you can trigger this modification event somehow with VBA, I think there's better way to handle your read-only cells. Set them as protectable in cell format window, and then protect your sheet. After that everybody would be able to edit all the cells except the ones you marked as protectable.

Comment: I've already done that.But on a cell selection which is editable I want to launch a button

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub a()
    CreateObject("wscript.shell").SendKeys "{F2}"
    DoEvents    'Sync SendKeys
    MsgBox "IsCellInEdition ? " & IsCellInEdition
    
    CreateObject("wscript.shell").SendKeys "{ESC}"
    DoEvents    'Sync SendKeys
    MsgBox "IsCellInEdition ? " & IsCellInEdition
End Sub

'-----------------------------------
'Checks if a cell is in edition mode
'-----------------------------------
Function IsCellInEdition() As Boolean
    Dim ErrNumber As Long
    
    'Cell remains in edition mode ?
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    ErrNumber = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If ErrNumber = 1004 Then IsCellInEdition = True
End Function
```