# VB - Excel, crash on worksheet.copy() if a selected cell has new text

Tags: vb.net, excel-2010

I'm new to VB and am experiencing a frustrating crash when trying to copy a worksheet.

calling `worksheet.Copy()` works most of the time, but when a user has entered text in a cell and not deselected that cell or pressed enter, it crashes with the message "Copy message of Worksheet class failed," and error code -2146827284. Can anyone enlighten me as to why this is happening?

Here's the entire sub (which is called when the user clicks a button in an excel ribbon)

```
Friend Sub CheckSheet(ByRef worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet, ByVal testType As List(Of String), ByRef guide As List(Of String), ByRef display As Dictionary(Of String, Boolean), ByRef URL As String)

        'Read the labels and units from the current worksheet
        Dim readings = loadReadings(worksheet, 3, 3, 4)
        If readings Is Nothing Then 'If the readings are not successfully loaded
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Create a copy of the workbook to be processed to put the results in
        Dim originalFilename As String = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        Dim using1904system As Boolean = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Date1904

        worksheet.Copy() 'FIXME Crash here if selected cell has newly entered text

        worksheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.Date1904 = using1904system 'Make sure the new worksheet uses the same date option

        'Get requests from worksheet
        Dim cellMap = New Dictionary(Of String, Range)
        Dim allRequests = getRequests(worksheet, readings, cellMap, 5, testType, guidelines, 1, 2, 3)

        'Gets the results from the server and outputs them to a new Excel workbook
        Dim success = processResults(allRequests, URL, worksheet, display, cellMap, 5, originalFilename, testType, guidelines)
        If Not success Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Set focus to the checked worksheet
        worksheet.Activate()

    End Sub
```

**Edit:**

I've tried to programmatically deselect the cell by selecting a different cell, e.g.:

```
worksheet.Range("A1").Activate()
```

but that doesn't seem to have any effect (the crash still occurs). My add in only calls the copy method when explicitly instructed to do so by the user, so it seems like a pretty safe assumption that if the user has stopped entering text in a cell and clicked the button to run my add in, they're done entering text in the box.

Answer (score -1):

The Reason for this Problem is that Excel waits for the User - Excel beeing a User-centric application, all your Actions have to wait until the User finished his data-entering.
I thin this beheavior is useful, since the Text of the cell is technically undefined at this moment, so you would produce crapps results if the user edits a cell, presses your button and then finishes entering data - you would have used the old data, which is not useful.

I have seen this thread: [How to detect a cell is selected for editing in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572633/how-to-detect-a-cell-is-selected-for-editing-in-excel)
That should help
Otherwise, you could wrap the code in a try...catch block and parse the returned error code. if it is your error code display a message like "ooops please finish editing the textbox". But i think events would be better.

Comment: Really? But the text of the cell should NOT be undefined. The user has entered text, stopped, taken their hand off the keyboard, grabbed the mouse, and deliberately clicked the button that starts my program. I have trouble seeing how a crash with a cryptic error message is useful in this situation. A prompt telling the user that they have to deselect the cell before running my program (which is indeed how I've currently hacked my way around the problem), is just annoying from a user perspective, as they've obviously finished entering data if they've clicked the button.

Comment: Undefnded might be the wrong word - a more appropiate Idea might be a file: The user has finished entering data, but has NOT explicitly closed the file - so other programs cannot acess the file.

Comment: Ok, so is there a way for me to close the file for the user?